# Operator for left side being within δ distance from right side

Tags: notation, upper-lower-bounds

Is there a mathematical operator symbol to express that the left side of the operator is within $\delta$ of the right side? For example:
$$y - \delta \leqslant x \leqslant y + \delta$$
could be expressed using this operator I'm looking for:
$$x \text{ near}_\delta\text{ } y$$
where $\text{near}_\delta$ is the operator I hope to find. If an operator for this doesn't exist, what would be an appropriate operator to define for this purpose?

I'm looking specifically for operator notation because ultimately I need to have cases:
$$x \text{ near}_\delta\text{ } \begin{cases}0&\text{if }w<0,\\y^2&\text{if }0 \leqslant w \leqslant 2,\\-y + \log_z y&\text{if }w>2.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Is there a reason you want an operator instead of just writing something like $|x-f(x)|\le\delta$?

Comment: @MarkS. I mentioned the reason at the end. I want a convenient and readable way to write a bunch of cases where $x$ is near different values based on conditions.

Comment: That example makes no sense. How can we say that $x \operatorname{near}_\delta y$ whenever $x < 0$, as the first line of your example says? The other two lines aren't much better.

Comment: @at01 What I was getting at is that a traditional compact way to do that would be to define $f(x)$ to be your thing with cases, and then write $|x-f(x)|\le\delta$. It's a bit rare to define a new infix relation for something that can already be pretty compactly expressed in traditional notation, so I was wondering if there was some other motivation.

Comment: @DavidK I changed the conditions to use a different variable than $x$ if that helps. I was just giving an example.

Comment: @MarkS. I see what you're suggesting. That does make sense. In my case, I'll have to define many piecewise functions to use in $|x - f(x)| \leqslant \delta$. It would be simpler and easier to read, I think, with an infix relation.

Comment: When you have a need for a specific notation that isn't part of the common vocabulary, you are allowed to introduce the notation. Just be sure to clearly define it before using it. And if you use it again well separated from earlier usages, be kind and point back to where the notation is defined. I would suggest $x \approx_\delta y$ or $x \overset\delta\approx y$ instead of $x\ \text{near}_\delta\ y$, but that is just a personal preference.

Comment: "Making up your own notation" is done more often than you probably think. The key (as noted above) is a clear definition before usage. The advantages of the previously suggested $\approx_\delta$ and $\overset\delta\approx$ are that $x\approx y$ is already a well-known symbol meaning "$x$ is near $y$" (it just doesn't say how near), and there is an established precedent to modify a relational symbol by putting something in the subscript position (like $\approx_\delta$) or on top (like $\overset\delta\approx$).

Comment: @PaulSinclair and David K, thank you. I like $\approx_\delta$! Please put that as an answer so I can award the credit. Is there a standard way to define this new notation?

Comment: "Let $x\approx_\delta y$ mean ...", "Denoting $|x - y| < \delta$ by ...", or "[*expression involving the notation*], where $x\approx_\delta y$ means ..." are all common ways. Every math book you have ever read is replete with more examples of how such notations are introduced.